# gcc inline assembler: "leal 2(%%ebx,%%eax,$2),%1" doesn't assemble but it does without the $

Tags: gcc, assembly, att

This is first time I write assembler code.
At the very first beginning, I wrote

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x,y;
    asm("movl $2,%eax");
    asm volatile(
                    "movl $1,%0\n\t"
                    "movl %0,%%ebx\n\t"
                    "leal 2(%%ebx,%%eax,$2),%1"
                    :"=m"(x),"=r"(y)
                    );
    printf("x is %d, y is %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

The gcc 5.4.0 compiler gives error message:

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:7: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
test.c:7: Error: expecting scale factor of 1, 2, 4, or 8: got `$2'
```

Then I change the

```
"leal 2(%%ebx,%%eax,$2),%1"
```

to

```
"leal 2(%%ebx,%%eax,2),%1"
```

It is ok. However, is $2 not equal to 2?

Comment: In this syntax the number must be without $, that’s just how it’s defined. Normally $ would mean a constant but since you can’t have anything else than a specific constant in the addressing mode it doesn’t use a prefix to say this is a constant.

Comment: FYI, clobbering `%ebx` without telling the compiler (with a clobber constraint) will cause unpredictable results.  (Well, predictable if you read the final asm output from the compiler with `gcc -O2 -S`).  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Answer (score 0):

In AT&T syntax, the dollar sign `$` indicates an *immediate operand.* For example, it distinguishes

```
add 16,%eax
```

(add value at address `16` to `eax`) from

```
add $16,%eax
```

(add `16` to `eax`). Note that this isn't related to integer constants at all. You could just as well writ

```
add foo,%eax
```

and

```
add $foo,%eax
```

where `foo` is some symbol. The `disp(base,index,scale)` notation denotes a memory operand using *SIB addressing.* Each of the three pieces in this addressing mode has a fixed purpose, so there is no point in decorating `scale` with anything. After all, we have already chosen an addressing mode, so why should there be another operand-type indicator within the parentheses? Note that the `%` in front of register names is still mandatory because it distinguishes the register name from a macro or symbol name.